# MenuItem не является классом атрибута, стандартный атрибут но редактор не видит

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
public class MenuTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Add a menu item named "Do Something" to MyMenu in the menu bar.
    [MenuItem("MyMenu/Do Something")]
    static void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("Doing Something...");
    }

    // Validated menu item.
    // Add a menu item named "Log Selected Transform Name" to MyMenu in the menu bar.
    // We use a second function to validate the menu item
    // so it will only be enabled if we have a transform selected.
    [MenuItem("MyMenu/Log Selected Transform Name")]
    static void LogSelectedTransformName()
    {
        Debug.Log("Selected Transform is on " + Selection.activeTransform.gameObject.name + ".");
    }

    // Validate the menu item defined by the function above.
    // The menu item will be disabled if this function returns false.
    [MenuItem("MyMenu/Log Selected Transform Name", true)]
    static bool ValidateLogSelectedTransformName()
    {
        // Return false if no transform is selected.
        return Selection.activeTransform != null;
    }

    // Add a menu item named "Do Something with a Shortcut Key" to MyMenu in the menu bar
    // and give it a shortcut (ctrl-g on Windows, cmd-g on macOS).
    [MenuItem("MyMenu/Do Something with a Shortcut Key %g")]
    static void DoSomethingWithAShortcutKey()
    {
        Debug.Log("Doing something with a Shortcut Key...");
    }

    // Add a menu item called "Double Mass" to a Rigidbody's context menu.
    [MenuItem("CONTEXT/Rigidbody/Double Mass")]
    static void DoubleMass(MenuCommand command)
    {
        Rigidbody body = (Rigidbody)command.context;
        body.mass = body.mass * 2;
        Debug.Log("Doubled Rigidbody's Mass to " + body.mass + " from Context Menu.");
    }

    // Add a menu item to create custom GameObjects.
    // Priority 1 ensures it is grouped with the other menu items of the same kind
    // and propagated to the hierarchy dropdown and hierarchy context menus.
    [MenuItem("GameObject/MyCategory/Custom Game Object", false, 10)]
    static void CreateCustomGameObject(MenuCommand menuCommand)
    {
        // Create a custom game object
        GameObject go = new GameObject("Custom Game Object");
        // Ensure it gets reparented if this was a context click (otherwise does nothing)
        GameObjectUtility.SetParentAndAlign(go, menuCommand.context as GameObject);
        // Register the creation in the undo system
        Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(go, "Create " + go.name);
        Selection.activeObject = go;
    }
}
```

Ошибку указывает на сам атрибут все библиотеки я добавил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас точно никакие неймпейсы больше не подключены?

Comment: Неа, я просто скопировал и вставил код с сайта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что у вас в проекте где-то есть скрипт с таким же классом (`MenuItem`) и вам нужно его переименовать (как скрипт, так и класс)